# Heroku Push Problem part 2 - Postgresql - PGError Relations does not exist - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Ok so got through my last problem with the difference between Postgresql and SQLite and seems like Heroku is telling me I have another one. I am new to ruby and rails so a lot of this stuff I can't decipher at first. Looking for a little direction here. The error message and PostsController Index are below. I checked my routes.rb file and all seems well there but I could be missing something. I will post if you need.

```
Processing PostsController#index (for 99.7.50.140 at 2010-04-23 15:19:22) [GET]

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  relation "tags" does not exist
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"tags"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
):
```

PostsController#index

```
  def index
    @tag_counts = Tag.count(:group => :tag_name, 
       :order => 'count_all DESC', :limit => 20)
       conditions, joins = {}, :votes

    @ugtag_counts = Ugtag.count(:group => :ugctag_name, 
       :order => 'count_all DESC', :limit => 20)
       conditions, joins = {}, :votes

    @vote_counts = Vote.count(:group => :post_title, 
          :order => 'count_all DESC', :limit => 20)
          conditions, joins = {}, :votes


       unless(params[:tag_name] || "").empty?
         conditions = ["tags.tag_name = ? ", params[:tag_name]]
         joins = [:tags, :votes]
       end
       @posts=Post.paginate(
                 :select => "posts.*, count(*) as vote_total", 
                 :joins => joins, 
                 :conditions=> conditions, 
                 :group => "votes.post_id, posts.id ", 
                 :order => "created_at DESC",
                 :page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
        @popular_posts=Post.paginate(
                 :select => "posts.*, count(*) as vote_total", 
                 :joins => joins, 
                 :conditions=> conditions, 
                 :group => "votes.post_id, posts.id", 
                 :order => "vote_total DESC",
                 :page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
      format.json { render :json => @posts }
      format.atom
    end
  end
```

Comment: have you tried "heroku rake db:migrate" ?

Comment: @Comptrol "heroku rake db:migrate" did the trick for me. Cmd line output said that that cmd was deprecated though and "heroku run rake" should be used instead. So does this mean that every time I make a db change locally via a migration that after running "git push heroku master" I then have to follow up with a "heroku run rake"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What all gems are used by this Rails app? Do you have a .gems manifest file in the root of the app for heroku to auto detect and install? i see that you are using will paginate gem. If you haven't added the gems to the .gems file then i guess thats the trouble. If you haven't done that then this would be the best place to look for help: [Heroku | Managing Gems](http://docs.heroku.com/gems)

Comment: I am using will_paginate, paperclip, wysihat-engine. They all have lines in the environment.rb file. Isn't the environment.rb file where heroku looks to auto install this stuff?

Comment: Oops! No. Heroku won't auto detect from the environment.rb file. You need a special .gems manifest file in the root of your app. Create one, and add all your gems in it. The procedure is described in the link above. I guess with that all your problems with heroku stands solved. :)

Comment: and why is this related to the issue? the others answers address it way better!

Answer (score 2):

I was running into a similar "PGError: ERROR:  relation "..." does not exist" problem when upgrading to from rails 3.0.3 to rails 3.0.5 - it looks as though the database name pluralization algorithm had changed. What I used to have to pluralize: "project_metadatas" is now referred to as "project_metadata".

The fix for me was to add a simple migration that renamed the offending table:

```
class MetadataName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_table :project_metadatas, :project_metadata
  end

  def self.down
    rename_table :project_metadata, :project_metadatas
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks strange:

```
WHERE a.attrelid = '"tags"'::regclass
```

The single quotes delimit a string literal, so the inner double-quotes are treated as part of the string.  So it's looking for a table name that actually has `"` characters as part of the name.

I'm not sure how the Rails plumbing has generated that query, so I don't have anything to suggest to fix it.  Sorry...

But this definitely seems to be a [Leaky Abstraction](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html) problem.  :-)

Comment: That isn't very comforting. Don't really understand all that is in the link you provided. I def don't have a table with " in it as I don't even think that is possible. Hopefully someone else has seen this before. I'm new to ruby, rails, and programming in general so this is tough stuff for me.

Comment: Normally Rails infers the name of the table from your ActiveRecord class names, but this can be overridden.  Perhaps you've specified the SQL table name somewhere and accidentally included " characters?

Answer (score 1):

hi 
i found something
so my problème was:

```
 `enter code here`WHERE a.attrelid = '"posts"'::regclass
```

are some of you using gem like rails_admin with initializer file ? 
because when i comment my action in my initializer file related to this model my migartion works :)

```
 #config.model Post do
 #  field :body, :text do
 #    ckeditor true
 #  end
 #end
```

So maybe (i m not sur) initializer are before rake task and. It ask for a model but there
is not sql table, so bug.
anyway this action work for my test and production env :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the problem was that I had forgotten to migrate the database using rake.  The following got everything working correctly:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the source of this issue in my rails app, thanks to Bill Karwin's tip above:

When I update my db schema by running rake db:schema:dump on my dev box, it replaces some (but not all) symbols with enquoted strings...

e.g.,

```
add_index :taggings, ["vectors"]
```

becomes

```
add_index "taggings", ["vectors"]
```

This doesn't cause any problems on my dev box, but heroku doesn't seem to handle the discrepancy well when the db is created from scratch, but not on a db:push.

As soon as I manually switched the table names symbols, my app started playing nice again.

If anyone knows the reason for this offhand, I'd be interested...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I bet your table name must be 'tag', not 'tags'.

If you change your table name to 'tags' in Postgresql, it will work. But why? I gave the singular model name, GHOST takes the plural.

Answer (score 0):

To add the line below to your `/config/environment.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me but only en test and prod env.

```
rake db:migrate
```

ok

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
rake aborted!
PGError: ERREUR:  la relation « posts » n'existe pas
LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"posts"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"posts"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after a big push even though I remembered to run migrations. For me the solution was to restart:

```
heroku restart
```